# multi column indexes involving nulls

Tags: postgresql

I have a where clause

```
WHERE (v.regstnum = voters.regstnum OR voters.regstnum IS NULL) 
AND (v.regstfrac = voters.regstfrac OR voters.regstfrac IS NULL) 
AND (v.regstname = voters.regstname OR voters.regstname IS NULL) 
AND (v.regsttype = voters.regsttype OR voters.regsttype IS NULL) 
AND (v.regstpredirection = voters.regstpredirection OR voters.regstpredirection IS NULL) 
AND (v.regstpostdirection = voters.regstpostdirection OR voters.regstpostdirection IS NULL) 
AND (v.regunittype = voters.regunittype OR voters.regunittype IS NULL) 
AND (v.regunitnum = voters.regunitnum OR voters.regunitnum IS NULL) 
AND (v.regcity = voters.regcity OR voters.regcity IS NULL) 
AND v.fname != voters.fname)
```

and an index `"address2" btree (regstnum, regstfrac, regstname, regsttype, regstpredirection, regstpostdirection, regunittype, regunitnum, regcity)`

But according to explain the index isn't being used.

My guess is it caused by the IS NULL part that I had to add because I have many nulls and the query wasn't working without the IS NULL part.

So how do I rewrite my query to deal with the nulls and use the index?

Table structure:

```
         Column         | Type  | Modifiers
------------------------+-------+-----------
 slug                   | text  | not null
 voters_at_same_address | jsonb |
 statevoterid           | text  |
 countyvoterid          | text  |
 title                  | text  |
 fname                  | text  |
 mname                  | text  |
 lname                  | text  |
 namesuffix             | text  |
 birthdate              | date  |
 gender                 | text  |
 regstnum               | text  |
 regstfrac              | text  |
 regstname              | text  |
 regsttype              | text  |
 regunittype            | text  |
 regstpredirection      | text  |
 regstpostdirection     | text  |
 regunitnum             | text  |
 regcity                | text  |
 regstate               | text  |
 regzipcode             | text  |
 countycode             | text  |
 precinctcode           | text  |
 precinctpart           | text  |
 legislativedistrict    | text  |
 congressionaldistrict  | text  |
 mail1                  | text  |
 mail2                  | text  |
 mail3                  | text  |
 mail4                  | text  |
 mailcity               | text  |
 mailzip                | text  |
 mailstate              | text  |
 mailcountry            | text  |
 registrationdate       | date  |
 absenteetype           | text  |
 lastvoted              | date  |
 statuscode             | text  |
 dflag                  | text  |
Indexes:
    "voters_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (slug)
    "address" btree (regstnum, regstfrac, regstname, regsttype, regunittype, regstpredirection, regstpostdirection, regunitnum, regcity, regstate, regzipcode)
    "address2" btree (regstnum, regstfrac, regstname, regsttype, regstpredirection, regstpostdirection, regunittype, regunitnum, regcity)
    "names" btree (fname, lname)
```

Explain:

```
Index Scan using names on voters  (cost=0.43..840447.35 rows=3 width=58)
   Index Cond: ((fname = 'MICHAEL'::text) AND (lname = 'BEEBE'::text))
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Aggregate  (cost=280143.59..280143.60 rows=1 width=17)
           ->  Seq Scan on voters v  (cost=0.00..280143.56 rows=1 width=17)
                 Filter: (((regstnum = voters.regstnum) OR (voters.regstnum IS NULL)) AND ((regstfrac = voters.regstfrac) OR (voters.regstfrac IS NULL)) AND ((regstname = voters.regstname) OR (voters.regstname IS NULL)) AND ((regsttype = voters.
regsttype) OR (voters.regsttype IS NULL)) AND ((regstpredirection = voters.regstpredirection) OR (voters.regstpredirection IS NULL)) AND ((regstpostdirection = voters.regstpostdirection) OR (voters.regstpostdirection IS NULL)) AND ((regunittype
= voters.regunittype) OR (voters.regunittype IS NULL)) AND ((regunitnum = voters.regunitnum) OR (voters.regunitnum IS NULL)) AND ((regcity = voters.regcity) OR (voters.regcity IS NULL)) AND (fname <> voters.fname))
(6 rows)
```

Full query:

```
SELECT fname, 
       mname, 
       lname, 
       Date_part('year', Age(birthdate)) :: int AS age, 
       birthdate, 
       regstnum, 
       regstfrac, 
       regstname, 
       regsttype, 
       regstpredirection, 
       regstpostdirection, 
       regunittype, 
       regunitnum, 
       regcity, 
       (SELECT Array_to_json(Array_agg(Row_to_json(ROW(v.fname, v.lname, 
                                                   Date_part('year', Age( 
                                                   v.birthdate)) :: int, 
               v.birthdate)))) 
        FROM   voters AS v 
        WHERE  ( v.regstnum = voters.regstnum 
                  OR voters.regstnum IS NULL ) 
               AND ( v.regstfrac = voters.regstfrac 
                      OR voters.regstfrac IS NULL ) 
               AND ( v.regstname = voters.regstname 
                      OR voters.regstname IS NULL ) 
               AND ( v.regsttype = voters.regsttype 
                      OR voters.regsttype IS NULL ) 
               AND ( v.regstpredirection = voters.regstpredirection 
                      OR voters.regstpredirection IS NULL ) 
               AND ( v.regstpostdirection = voters.regstpostdirection 
                      OR voters.regstpostdirection IS NULL ) 
               AND ( v.regunittype = voters.regunittype 
                      OR voters.regunittype IS NULL ) 
               AND ( v.regunitnum = voters.regunitnum 
                      OR voters.regunitnum IS NULL ) 
               AND ( v.regcity = voters.regcity 
                      OR voters.regcity IS NULL ) 
               AND v.fname != voters.fname)     AS voters_at_same_address 
FROM   voters 
WHERE  "fname" = 'TIMOTHY' 
       AND "lname" = 'CLEMANS';
```

Comment: pleasse put explain plan too, as much as table structure